# React data undefined in component after callback from class object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, callback, undefined

I have a **functional component** and a **class object** which handles some stuff.
That class, created in a component does some calculations, then calls a callback function received from component and stored as a reference in the class object.

I don't think this is a proper way of approaching this issue but I dont really have a clue on how to do this different.
I believe that its an issue of where the function was called from but thats about it.

The class:

```js
export const myClass {
    private static instance: myClass;

    callbackRef:() => void;

    private constructor() {
        callbackRef = () : void => console.log('unset Callback');
    }

    static getInstance(): myClass {
        if (!myClass.instance) {
            myClass.instance = new myClass();
        }
        return myClass.instance;
    }

    setCallback(callbackFn: () => void) : void {
        this.callbackRef = callbackFn;
    }

    doSth() {
        this.callbackRef();
    }
}
```

The component:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const MyComponent = () : JSX.Element => {
    const [someState, setSomeState] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const someCallback = () : void => {
        console.log(someState)
    }

    const myclass = myClass.getInstance();
    myclass.setCallback(someCallback);
    myclass.doSth();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(someState);
    }, []);

    return(<></>);
}
```

console output will be
`false undefined`

To my understanding if MyComponent was a class component I could simply this.someCallback.bind(this)
however it's a functional component and `this` does not exist.

I've also tried using

```js
const someCallback = useCallback(() : void => {
    console.log(someState);
}, []);
```

and passing it to class instance, to no avail.

Ay help would be highly appreciated, thank you D: !
(Tips on how to handle this kind of calculations aswell ;_;)

Comment: I can't really get what's your issue here and what exactly you're trying to achieve, but I guess there's a more "React" way to do that. That being said, there are some problems with the code you posted, starting with the fact that your "class" is defined as a constant, not a class. After some fixes, what I get in the console is `false false` and not `false undefined`: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-5qqain). Not sure if that solves your issue.

Comment: Also, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) do exist on Javascript functions (a React function component is just a function).